# How can modify my code to find all specific attributes for all <a> tags with a specific class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use **beautifulsoup** to pull out all `data-bk` attributes (`x`, `y`, `z` in the below) from `<a>` tags with `class="bk3-link"`. An example of the html is below:

```
<a class="bk3-link" data-bk="x" ... >
<a class="bk3-link" data-bk="y" ... >
<a class="bk3-link" data-bk="z" ... >
```

I've tried pulling all `data-bk` attributes but they're used elsewhere in the html. I've tried searching for all `<a>` tags with `class = "bk3-link"` and then all `data-bk` within. I can't get my head around the syntax I need to do this.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {"User-Agent": "Google Chrome v6.9"}
r = requests.get("https://www.randomwebsite", headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

data1 = soup.find_all("a", {"data-bk" : True})
data2 = soup.find_all("a", class="bk3-link").find("a", data-bk)
```

If I print data 1 to the console I have an enormous amount of html, including other `data-bk` attributes. I really need to only return the `data-bk` attributes found within `<a>` tags with `class="bk3-link"`. Trying to run the data2 I get:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: This is the website:https://www.oddschecker.com/football/english/premier-league/west-ham-v-man-city/winner
I'm trying to scrape the bookmaker short codes, and then eventually the odds. eg:<a class="bk3-link" data-bk="UN" ... >. I need a list of UN etc for each

Comment: You probably need to deal with the hyphen in `data-bk`. Should there be quotation marks around that in your last line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is using CSS selector `".bk3-link[data-bk]"` - this will select all tags with class `bk3-link` which contain attribute `data-bk`:

```
data = '''
<a class="bk3-link" data-bk="x">xxx</a>
<a data-bk="y">DONT SELECT</a>
<a class="bk3-link" data-bk="y">xxx</a>
<a class="bk3-link" data-bk="z">xxx</a>
<a data-bk="q">DONT SELECT</a>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for tag in soup.select('.bk3-link[data-bk]'):
    print(tag['data-bk'])
```

Prints:

```
x
y
z
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify multiple attributes in `find_all()`.

```
data1 = soup.find_all("a", attrs = {"class": "bk3-link", "data-bk": True})
```